# Set time to execute Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have the following function hooked into my Wordpress plugin.

```
function before_submit() { 
    document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';
}
```

This hook is being called before it submits a form. Now what i would like to do is to get the div id `page-loader` for a specific number of seconds, before it actually submits the form. I've read about the settimeout function and tried some stuff, but i cannot get it working. I guess the settimeout function is to run a script **after** a certain number of seconds instead of running it **for** a number of seconds correct?

So i'd like the script to have a 'running time' of, for instance, 4 seconds. Now it runs the script and submits the form immidiately

Tried this but it's not working:

```
function before_submit()
{

function partA() {
document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';
  window.setTimeout(partB,1000)
}

function partB() {
//let's go submit the form
}
}
```

Please help me out.
Thank you so much!

Comment: not sure I understand what you want, but check [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function

Comment: What do you mean running for a number of seconds? once you run it, that's it.

Comment: Are you submitting form via Ajax? If so, `setTimout` will not work, use callback functions

Comment: So you want the user to click the button and for the code to delay submission of the form until the timer thing has completed?

Comment: Have the function set the style, then it can use `setTimeout` to run another function after a certain amount of time to submit the form.

Comment: You have to block sending your data (either blocking the submit event on the form or don't send the AJAX request), then from your `setTimeout()` within your `before_submit()`, programmatically submit your data (either call `form.submit` with `form` being a reference to your form element, or send the AJAX request). `setInterval()` should have no bearing.

Comment: Well, i'd like to run the script and i'd like the script to have a 'running time' of, for instance, 4 seconds. Now it runs the script and submits the form immidiately... Hope this is a bit more clear.. ?

Comment: Why is this code not working?
`function before_submit()
{

function partA() {
document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';
  window.setTimeout(partB,1000)
}

function partB() {
//let's go submit the form
}
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the format you're looking for:

```
// Note, in the fiddle, this is run during the window.onload event.
var test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('submit', function before_submit(e){
    document.getElementById('wait').style.display = 'block';

    setTimeout(function wait(){
        // After waiting for five seconds, submit the form.
        test.submit();
    }, 5000);

    // Block the form from submitting.
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmef40c5/

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I checked out the jsfiddle and that is indeed what i want. I tried however to implement this in my form but couldn't make it work like that. My form id = `form11` and my waiting div id is `page-loader`. How to implement this in my code? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you notice the mention of it running from the `window.onload` event?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rmef40c5/1/ And an upvote and marked as the answer would be nice. `;)`

Comment: Thank you, I should be able to figure it out from here (Y)

Answer (score 0):

you have to prevent the default bevaviour e.g. with `<input type="button" onclick="before_submit();return false;" />`

Comment: Tried adding that but what exactly is it supposed to do? What code do i need for function before_submit() ?

Comment: <pre><form action="asd.html" method="post" id="myForm">  
<input type="button" onclick="before_submit();return false;" />  
</form>  

<Script>   
 function before_submit()  
 {  
 // document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';  
 setTimeout(to_submit_form,5000);  
}  
  
function to_submit_form(){  
alert("submit");  
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();  
}  

</script></pre>

Comment: Won't work, for some reason it just submits the form.

Comment: @RobbertT - Because you have to prevent the `submit` event; what wormonic is showing won't work, because the `return false` is on the wrong element. See my answer for more details (which uses a different form to prevent submit).

Comment: Jared is right,
     <form action="asd.html" method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit="before_submit();return false;"> 
     <input type="submit" />  
 </form>

try it this way

Answer (score -1):

It may work for you. 
first call a before_submit function on Click button, then call a function for page-loader then after some seconds it will submit your form.

```
<form action="asd.html" method="post" id="myForm">
<input type="button" onclick="before_submit()" />
</form>

<Script>
function before_submit()
{
// document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';
 setTimeout(to_submit_form,5000);
}

function to_submit_form(){
alert("submit");
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

</script>
```

Comment: You would *not* use `setInterval()`. Why would you serially resubmit the form every 3 seconds?

Comment: sorry, check this again ..! (tested)

Comment: Thanks, see what you are doing but its not working. For some reason the form won't wait for the the `to_submit_form`.. It sends the form after it is done loading. I also tried to implement the `to_submit_form` into the `before_submit` without success...